# How to calculate grand total servlet

Tags: java, servlets

Hi in my servlet I've got for loop to display content of cart, I want add to it "grand total" for all items in cart to calculate total for item I have

```
public double getTotalCost() {
        return (getItemCount() * getItemPrice());
}
```

my for loop looks like

```
for (SimpleItem item : previousItems) {
out.println("<TR>"
+ "<TD>"+ item.getItemName() + "</TD>"
+ "<TD>"+ item.getItemArtistDirector() + "</TD>"
+ "<TD>"+ formatter.format(item.getItemPrice()) + "</TD>"
+ "<TD><DIV>"+ "<FORM id ='2' ACTION='OrderPage'>" 
+ "<INPUT TYPE='HIDDEN' NAME='title' VALUE='" + item.getItemName()+ "'>"
+ "<INPUT TYPE='HIDDEN' NAME='artistDirector' VALUE='" + item.getItemArtistDirector()+ "'>"
+ "<INPUT TYPE='HIDDEN' NAME='price' VALUE='" + item.getItemPrice()+ "'>"
+ "<INPUT TYPE='TEXT' NAME='numItems' SIZE=3 VALUE='" + item.getItemCount() + "'>" + "<SMALL>"
+ "<button TYPE='SUBMIT' formaction = 'OrderPage'>Update Order</button>" + "</SMALL>"
+ "</FORM>" + "</DIV></TD>"
+ " <TD>"+ formatter.format(item.getTotalCost())+"</TD>"
+ "<TD>"+ item.getTotal() + "</TD>"
);
}
```

My question is how my method for grand total must looks like I have tried

```
   public double getTotal(){
        Double temp = getTotalCost();
        if(getTotalCost()!=temp){
          temp = temp + getTotalCost();
        }
        return(temp);
    }
```

Comment: Could you use MVC approach and forward to a JSP rather than writing the entire HTML in the Servlet?

Comment: I haven't done anything in jsp and mvc and this is last thing to do in this servlet I was able to display "results in jsp table" but that was difficult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you forgot to close your `TR` there.

As for your grand total, you realize that a grand total is not something that applies to each item. It is the total sum of all the costs of all the items. So first, you are not supposed to display it in every row like you do the items.

Second, regarding your method: for the same reason, you cannot calculate a grand total in the class of a single item. You can only calculate a grand total when you can see the entire collection of items. So adding a method like that to `SimpleItem` like you have `getTotalCost()` is not going to work.

You could add it as a method to the servlet, by passing it the collection, looping and summing. But I suggest, since you are already looping, that you simply calculate the grand total while you are already looping.

So add a declaration before your loop:

```
double grandTotal = 0.0D;
```

And inside your loop, add:

```
    grandTotal += item.getTotalCost()
```

At the end of the loop, you'll have a grand total. You'll need to display an extra row, where you'll put the grand total at the end, and only then to close with `</TABLE>`.

One last little note about your method: Don't declare a variable that's supposed to be used for calculations using a wrapper class like `Double`. Use `double` instead. Use wrapper classes only when you put things inside collections or otherwise need an Object. Using a temporary variable that is a Wrapper clase will cause the creation of many auto-box and auto-unbox objects and give the garbage collector a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

```
public double totalPrice(List<SimpleItem> items)
{
    double price = 0d;

    for (SimpleItem item : items)
    {
        price = price + item.getTotalCost();
    }
    return (price / items.size())
}
```